# Glassfish 3 DAS access error

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish, glassfish-3

Since I restart my DAS in Glassfish-3 I cant access to admin Glassfish-3 through the domain. When I start the domain I can see the following error:

> glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.com.sun.enterprise.container.common|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|User
>   [] from host MY_HOST does not have administration access|#]

```
    secure-enable-admin = true
```

When I try: wget -d http://IP:ADMIN_PORT

I get the conexion but I have an error in SSL handshake:

```
  ...
  SSL handshake failed.
  Closed fd 3
  The SSL connection could not be established.
  ...
```

I've checked my SSL certificates s1as and glassfish-instance in cacerts.jks and keycerts.jks and everything seems to be ok.

Any ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: have you enabled secure admin for your glassfish and restarted it after enableling it??

Comment: Yes, I have enabled secure admin and I restarted it many times.

Comment: Check Java version. I had the same problem even with Glassfish5. Upgrading Java to 1.8.0_151 fixed it